# Database Update Required - Update from command-line

Tags: database, upgrade, command-line

I just did upgrade my wordpress subtree of my website to the 3.6 branch and now the site tells me that I need to upgrade my database as well:

> Database Update Required

Nothing special so far, just business as normal. It suggests me to navigate to

```
http://example.com/wp-admin/upgrade.php?step=1
```

next.

As I'd like to automate the Wordpress Upgrade procedure a little from shell, I wonder how I can trigger executing the database upgrade from shell.

The information online is sparse and many are pointing to WP_Cli however I'm looking forward to an isolated command-line.

Answer (score 1):

Since:

1. upgrade endpoint in question doesn't seem to be behind login wall
2. no user action is required other than visiting it

I would imagine requesting the suggested URL with some CLI tool for HTTP requests (curl and wget are commonly available) should accomplish upgrade.

Comment: I did this with curl, it eventually will also work by executing the file on the commandline directly, just fiddling with this. But so far +1 curl looks good. But as you write, some restrictions apply.

Answer (score 1):

Core updates are supported in the [WP-CLI](http://wp-cli.org/).

> [`wp core update`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/core/update/) - Update WordPress.

```
# Update WordPress
$ wp core update
Updating to version 4.5.2 (en_US)...
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/wordpress-4.5.2-no-content.zip...
Unpacking the update...
Cleaning up files...
No files found that need cleaned up
Success: WordPress updated successfully.

# Update WordPress to latest version of 3.8 release
$ wp core update --version=3.8 ../latest.zip
Updating to version 3.8 ()...
Unpacking the update...
Cleaning up files...
File removed: wp-admin/js/tags-box.js
...
File removed: wp-admin/js/updates.min.
377 files cleaned up
Success: WordPress updated successfully.

# Update WordPress to 3.1 forcefully
$ wp core update --version=3.1 --force
Updating to version 3.1 (en_US)...
Downloading update from https://wordpress.org/wordpress-3.1.zip...
Unpacking the update...
Warning: Failed to fetch checksums. Please cleanup files manually.
Success: WordPress updated successfully.
```

Other update commands include:

> [`wp plugin update`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/plugin/update/) - Update one or more plugins.
>
> [`wp theme update`](http://wp-cli.org/commands/theme/update/) - Update one or more themes.